Problem adaptador Graphics
I have Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop installed. This is the only OS I have installed
Then I get the error:
I changed the graphics adapter from "More drivers" but after restarting, I cannot change the resolution and the Wi-Fi adapter does not load.
I don't know what to do because when I try to change the adapter again, it tells me that I have no connection.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

How can I change the graphics driver from the terminal?
3 appear to me:
nvidia 470
nvidia 470 server
xorg generic noveanu

Can be closed!!! Thanks
